# right aligned drop downbox (language)

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am novice but i need your help!

I have a menu which is centered position please visit http://www.rosettafaris.com/

On the far right hand side I want to add a language drop-down box where each language when chosen goes to its own page (e.g. en/index.html and de/index.html)

I also want it to work on mobile devices?

Can you help please?

```
body {
    font-family:'Kreon',serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
}
img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
section {
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    background:#F0A830;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
}
section::before,section::after {
    position:absolute;
    content: '';
}

/* Separators Styles */
.ss-style-top::before {
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    -webkit-background-size:25px 100%;
    -moz-background-size:25px 100%;
    -o-background-size:25px 100%;
    background-size:25px 100%;
    top:0;
    background-image:linear-gradient(315deg,#FFF 50%,transparent 50%),
    linear- gradient(45deg,#FFF 50%,transparent 50%);
    margin-top:-30px;
    z-index:100;
}
.ss-style-bottom::before {
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    -webkit-background-size:25px 100%;
    -moz-background-size:25px 100%;
    -o-background-size:25px 100%;
    background-size:25px 100%;
    top:0;
    background-image:linear-gradient(583deg,#FFF 50%,transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(136deg,#FFF 50%,transparent 50%);
    margin-top:0px;
    z-index: 100;
}


/*02. Header */
#header {
    background-image:url(../img/night.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size:/*@@prefixmycss->No equivalent*/;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:/*@@prefixmycss->No equivalent*/;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
}
.bg-overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:rgba(44,33,5,0.2);
    z-index:0;
}
#header .center {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    color:white;
}
#header .bottom {
    color:white;
}
#header .center .slogan {
    font-size:26px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
#header .banner h1 {
    font-size:100px;
    color:white;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#ed0121;
    padding:0px 18px;
}
#header .subtitle h4 {
    display:inline-block;
    background:white;
    color:#ed0121;
    font-size:38px;
    padding:0px 15px;
}
#header .bottom {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:30px;
}
#header .bottom a {
    font-size:36px;
    color:whitesmoke;
    position:relative;
    top:-5px;
}
.navbar-nav>li:nth-child(3) {
    margin-right: 110px;
}


/* 03. Navigation */
#menu {
    background:rgba(33,45,57,0.8);
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.navbar-brand h2 {
    margin-top:0;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition:all 0.4s;
    -o-transition:all 0.4s;
    transition:all 0.4s;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a    
{
    background:#ed0121;
    color:white;
    text-shadow:none;
}


/* 04. Services*/
.light-wrapper {
    background:#fbfbfb;
}
.inner {
    padding-top:100px;
    padding-bottom:100px;
}
.section-title {
    font-size:36px;
    line-height:40px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    font-weight:600;
}
.main.lead {
    margin-bottom:80px;
}
.lead {
    font-size:17px;
    line-height:24px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    color:#2e2e2e;
    position:relative;
}
.lead:after {
    position:absolute;
    content:' ';
    background:#ed0121;
    width:80px;
    height:3px;
    bottom:-22px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-40px;
}
.story .col-wrapper {
    padding:0 10px;
}
.story .icon-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    height:80px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}


/*  05. parallax */
.parallax {
    background:url(../img/parallax1.jpg) fixed no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size:/*@@prefixmycss->No equivalent*/;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:/*@@prefixmycss->No equivalent*/;
    background-size:cover;
    position:relative;
    color:#FFF;
}
.parallax .inner {
    padding-top:130px;
    padding-bottom:130px;
}
.parallax.parallax2 {
    background-image:url(../img/parallax2.jpg);
}
.bm10 {
    margin-bottom:10px !important;
}
.facts h4 {
    font-size:40px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.parallax h1,.parallax h2,.parallax h3,.parallax h4,.parallax h5,.parallax 
h6 {
    color:#fff;
}
.facts p {
    font-size:16px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin:0;
}
.story .icon-wrapper i {
    font-size:70px;
}
.facts i {
    font-size: 70px;
}


/*  06. Food menu  */
.menu-items {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.menu-titles h1 {   
    text-shadow:none;
    color:#ed0121;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
#food-menu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.menu-images img {
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:5px solid #dadada;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
}


/*  07. Special offers */
.hot-tag {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:15;
    display:inline-block;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    line-height:90px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#fff;
    -webkit-border-radius:100px;
    -moz-border-radius:100px;
    border-radius:100px;
}
.br-red {
    background-color:#ed0121 !important;
}
.br-lblue {
    background-color:#32c8de !important;
}
.br-green {
    background-color:#51d466 !important;
}
.pricing {
    border-top:1px solid #f1f1f1;
}
.pricing .pricing-item {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.pricing .pricing-item img {
    max-width:250px;
    float:left;
}
.pricing-item-details a,.pricing-item-details p,.pricing .lead {
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.pricing .pricing-item .pricing-item-details {
    margin-left:265px;
}
.pricing .pricing-item .pricing-item-details h3 {
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    font-size:22px;
}
.pricing .pricing-item .pricing-item-details p {
}
.pricing .pricing-item .pricing-item-details a.btn {
    margin-top:10px;
}
.pricing .pricing-item .pricing-item-details a.view-link {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:7px;
    font-size:12px;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #aeaeae;
}
.pricing .pricing-item .hot-tag {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin-top:-15px;
    margin-left:-15px;
    width:55px;
    height:55px;
    line-height:50px;
    font-size:23px;
    font-weight:700;
    border: 4px solid white;
}


/*  08. Reservation  */
.form-group {
    margin-bottom:24px;
}
.form-control[disabled],.form-control[readonly],fieldset[disabled] .form-  
control {
    cursor:not-allowed;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.form-control {
    height:38px;
    font-size:14px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color:transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow:none !important;
    box-shadow:none !important;
    -webkit-transition:none !important;
    -moz-transition:none !important;
    -o-transition:none !important;
    transition:none !important;
}

.form p {
    margin: 10px 0 30px 0;
}


/*  09. Chefs */
.chefs img {
    border:5px solid #e7e7e7;
    width: 80%;
}


/* 10. Footer  */
.dark-wrapper {
    background:#ed0121;
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.dark-wrapper .ss-style-top::before {
    background-image:linear-gradient(315deg,#ed0121 50%,transparent 50%),
    linear- gradient(45deg,#ed0121 50%,transparent 50%);
}
.social-bar {
    width:100%;
    text-align:right;
}
.social-bar a {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:11px;
    font-size:2.15em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    -webkit-transition:opacity 350ms ease;
    -moz-transition:opacity 350ms ease;
    -o-transition:opacity 350ms ease;
    transition:opacity 350ms ease;
}
.social-bar a:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.themeBy{
    color: #ed0121;
    background: white;
}

/* 11. Responsive styles */

@media (max-width: 991px){
    .pricing .pricing-item .pricing-item-details {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .pricing .pricing-item a img {
        float: none;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-nav {
        float:none !important;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        margin-left:9px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        display:inline-block;
        float:none;
    }
    #logo {
        position:absolute;
        display:block !important;
        width:110px;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-55px;
        background:black;
        -webkit-border-radius:0 0 100% 100%;
        -moz-border-radius:0 0 100% 100%;
        border-radius:0 0 100% 100%;
        padding: 12px;
    }
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    #header .banner h1 {
        font-size:60px;
    }
    #header .subtitle h4 {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    .social-bar {
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
}
```

Comment: #lang { position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 0; }

Comment: Can you please give me the exact code? I am a novice! Much appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a container with a list inside for you languages, you can use jquery like in this fiddle I've made to show and hide the menu: https://jsfiddle.net/nj55g0wz/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('.button');
    var menu = $('.hidden-menu');

    button.on('click',function(){
       menu.toggleClass('show'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi I tried it and i am getting this error. you can view it on the site. http://www.rosettafaris.com/

Comment: Also if you look on an iphone "the menu" is not aligned?

Comment: You are running the script before loading jquery. You should move the script to the end of the file, just within the closing `</html>` tag. Your scripts should be loaded earlier too, I would move them up into the `<head>` section, where you have modernizr.

Comment: Hi, I moved the JS Script to the bottom and I still dont know why it doesnt work? can you please help me! visit the same site  rosettafaris.com

Comment: You need to change the script to use your class and id names. Here's another fiddle that uses your html: https://jsfiddle.net/nj55g0wz/1/  Notice that I have added some classes to the span and ul in your HTML. Make sure you do this too. Also add the css for the class of .show`.

Comment: Hi #@sam_willis ! It works however now it moves the menu background. visit the site http://www.rosettafaris.com/index.html. Is there a better option? much appreciated!

Comment: Yes. on `.nav` add the propety `position: relative` and on `.lang-style` remove the `float: right;` and add `position: absolute;  right: 0;`